# In Perl, how can I check if a number is an element of an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, list, member

I'd like to write a short Perl prg that has 1 parameter (a 3 digit integer) passed to it, and depending which list it's a member of it returns the corresponding list's number. How can I achieve this, also is there any way to put a range of number as an element in a list ?

```
 ::Returns 1,2,3,4 Depending on testNum passed
 @gp1= (829,845,851,859,864,867);
 @gp2= ("826-828","830-839","843-844","847-850","852-854","860-862","883");
 @gp3= ("855-858",861,"863","865");
 @gp4= ("877-882",884);

 if ( ($ARGV[0]>=822 && $ARGV[0] <=824) || $ARGV[0]  is membergp1)
 {  
  return 1
 }
  if ( $ARGV[0]>=826 && $ARGV[0]<=828 || $ARGV[0] is memebr of group2
    return 2
  if $ARGV[0] is memebr of group3
      return 3
  if $ARGV[0] is memebr of group4
      return 4
```

Comment: I'd like something other than a for loop to test this. I don't know is there any build-in function that returns values if a variable is part of an array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three-digit numbers require an array of only one thousand elements. I suggest unpacking the data into an array and simply indexing that array with the passed parameter.

This program shows the idea. It expects the three-digit number on the command line.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @gp1=  qw(  829  845  851  859  864  867  );
my @gp2=  qw(  826-828  830-839  843-844  847-850  852-854  860-862  883  );
my @gp3=  qw(  855-858  861  863  865  );
my @gp4=  qw(  877-882  884  );

my @places;

my $n = 0;
for (\(@gp1, @gp2, @gp3, @gp4)) {
  $n++;
  for (@$_) {
    my @indices = /\d+/g;
    $places[$_] = $n for $indices[0] .. $indices[-1];
  }
}

my $val = $ARGV[0];
my $place = $places[$val];
printf "Value %s appears in %s\n", $val, $place ? "group $place" : "no group";
```

**output**

```
Value 832 appears in group 2
```

---

**Update**

Alternatively you could check whether the passed parameter matches each range as you process it.

The output is identical to the previous solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @gp1=  qw(  829  845  851  859  864  867  );
my @gp2=  qw(  826-828  830-839  843-844  847-850  852-854  860-862  883  );
my @gp3=  qw(  855-858  861  863  865  );
my @gp4=  qw(  877-882  884  );

my $val = $ARGV[0];

my $n = 0;
for (\(@gp1, @gp2, @gp3, @gp4)) {
  $n++;
  for (@$_) {
    my @indices = /\d+/g;
    if ($val >= $indices[0] and $val <= $indices[-1]) {
      printf "Value %s appears in group %d\n", $val, $n;
      exit;
    }
  }
}

printf "Value %s appears in no group\n", $val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all the lists in range objects using Number::Range (has to be downloaded):

```
  use Number::Range;
  my $range= Number::Range->new("23..98,103..150");
       if ($range->inrange("110")) {
           print "In range\n";
       } else {
           print "Not in range\n";
       }
```

See the following URL's:

http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/check-if-number-is-in-range-23-98t-574713.html
https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Range

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the issue of having ranges of numbers, a simple way to solve this problem is to make a hash of numbers and what group they're in.

```
my %num2group = (
    829 => 1,
    830 => 2,
    861 => 3,
    884 => 4,
    ...and so on...
);
```

Then you can simply query the hash to see what group (if any) a number is in.

```
my $group = $num2group{$number};
```

Rather than creating that hash by hand, you can generate it from your list of numbers.

```
$num2group{$_} = 1 for @grp1;
$num2group{$_} = 2 for @grp2;
...and so on...
```

This is where you'd handle ranges.  While generating `%num2group` you'd expand any ranges out into individual hash entries.  Assuming these ranges aren't enormous, this will make looking up groups efficient.

```
for my $num (@grp1) {
    if( /^(\d+)-(\d+)$/ ) {  # range
        $num2group{$_} = 1 for $1..$2;
    }
    else {
        $num2group{$num} = 1;
    }
}
```

Finally, rather than hard coding the group number, throw this into a subroutine.

```
sub add_to_group_hash {
    my($numbers, $group, $hash) = @_;

    for my $num (@$numbers) {
        if( /^(\d+)-(\d+)$/ ) {  # range
            $hash->{$_} = $group for $1..$2;
        }
        else {
            $hash->{$num} = $group;
        }
    }
 }

 add_to_group_hash(\@grp1, 1, \%num2group);
 add_to_group_hash(\@grp2, 2, \%num2group);
 ...and so on...
```

You can then add some error checking to make sure one number doesn't appear in two groups.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will want to use a function from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm), such as `any`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ranges using the range operator `..`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @lists = (
             [829,845,851,859,864,867],
             [826 .. 828, 830 .. 839, 843 .. 844, 847 .. 850, 852 .. 854, 860 .. 862, 883],
             [855 .. 858, 861, 863, 865],
             [877 .. 882, 884]
            );

say join ' ',
         "In list(s):",
         grep { grep $_ == $ARGV[0], @{ $lists[$_ - 1] }} 1 .. @lists;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to hard code the number of groups, or create a standalone array for each group.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::MoreUtils qw( first_index );

my @groups = (
    [829, 845, 851, 859, 864, 867 ],
    [
        826 .. 828,
        830 .. 839,
        843 .. 844,
        847 .. 850,
        852 .. 854,
        860 .. 862,
        883,
    ],
    [ 855 .. 858, 861, 863, 865 ],
    [ 877 .. 882, 884 ],
);

my ($candidate) = @ARGV;

my $group = first_index {
    (-1 < first_index { $candidate == $_ } @$_)
} @groups;

say $group > -1 ? $group : 'not found';
```